# I delete Windows' UFI partition during Manjaro installation

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, uefi, manjaro

During Manjaro installation, Windows' EFI partition was too small, so I delete and create a new one, now I can't enter in windows.
Here is `parted -l` result

```
Disk /dev/sda: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:  

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
1       1049kB  577MB  576MB   ntfs                  hidden, diag
2       577MB   368GB  367GB   ntfs                  msftdata
3       368GB   368GB  629MB   fat32                 boot, esp
4       368GB   380GB  11,8GB  linux-swap(v1)        swap
5       380GB   412GB  32,2GB  btrfs
6       412GB   512GB  99,9GB  btrfs
```

2 is windows, 5 is Linux /, and 6 is /home

Comment: "Windows' EFI partition was too small" - no, windows pretty much creates its boot partition to be the correct size - I'm guessing it was originally before the windows partition? Did you copy the contents after you moved it? You may need the install media, or windows recovery media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot into the Windows install USB and open the command prompt. Use `diskpart` to mount your disks accordingly and then run this command:

```
Bcdboot C:\Windows /l en-us /s x: /f ALL
```

Replace C:\Windows with your windows drive and X: with your boot partition.